# Mongodb aggregation $out dynamic collection name

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am looking for a way to incorporate the date into the collection name that is created in the $out stage of a Mongodb aggregation pipeline.
Something like this (but it doesnt work)

```
db.sales.aggregate([{$project: {account_number:1}},    
 {$out: "new_collection" + Date()}]);
```

This returns the following error;

> The specification of Stage 2 contains invalid JSON: Unexpected character '+' at line 1, col 18

Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Just interpolate `$out` collection name when creating query.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get any error message? or is it just the case that nothing happens?

Comment: I added the error message from the example syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date()` returns a long string version of the date which can contain characters that can't be used in collection names. For example:

```javascript
'Wed Dec 23 2015 22:47:53 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'
```

So you probably want to use something like `Date.now()` instead, which returns a ms count like `1450932419617` which will work in a collection name.

```javascript
{$out: "new_collection" + Date.now()}
```

giving you a valid collection name like `'new_collection1450932419617'`.